# PROBLEMA AL DECLARAR VARIABLES EN JAVA TIPO DOUBLE

Tags: java

solicito de su consejo viendo que puedo hacer con este problema, les comento estoy realizando un programa con JFrame en java y quiero declarar una variable de tipo Double en otra clase, pero al momento de querer declararlos me marca error les adjunto el código y les marco donde me merca problema.

```
public class EMPLEADO extends VENTANA1 implements PLANILLA{
    double IGGS, IVA;
```

Aqui es donde me da el problema

**IVA = 0.12;**
**IGSS = 0.0483;**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Como sugerencia, el código se comparte como texto, no como imagen. Aquí quienes intentan ayudar usan tu código para replicar el error y sugerir mejores respuestas, así que es contraintuitivo compartir una imagen y ponerlos a todos a transcribir. Evita también las mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Por cierto, tu error es tipográfico (cuando le asignas a IGSS, declaraste la variable como IGGS.

Comment: Como un comentario adicional, `EMPLEADO extends VENTANA1` no suena a la mejor jerarquía de clases del mundo... ¿en realidad un Empleado ES una Ventana1?

Comment: @Lobos, también se puede colocar como código fuera de un metodo/constructor usando `{}`. Mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer esa asignación, tendrías que colocar esas líneas entre `curly braces`:

```
double a, b;

{
    a = 5.4;
    b = 4.5;
}
```

Comment: una consulta que es el curly braces disculpa mi falta de conocimiento.

Comment: Los curly braces son los `{}`.

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono.

Comment: momento de usar las flechitas y marcar la respuesta como correcta :-D

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro, escribiste el nombre de las variables con mayúscula, por lo cual Java los toma como si fueran clases.

```
IVA = 0.12;//java intenta buscar la clase IVA y no la encuentra
```

Por este motivo es que los atributos se declaran con minúscula, ignorando esto para que tu código funcione deberías asignarlo así:

```
    {
        IVA = 0.12;
    }

// otra forma es asignarlo cuando lo declaras

double IVA = 0.12
```

es probable que el IDE te recomiende declararlo FINAL.

Comment: Muchas gracias entiendo que  {} son los curlybraces verdad

Answer (score 0):

La asignación de valores a las variables se debe dar solo de dos formas: o cuando las declara o dentro del alcance de un método o constructor. De esta forma el asignar valores deberia ser:

```
private double iva = 0.12D;
```

o

```
private double iva;

public void miMetodo(){
  this.iva = 0.12D;
}
```

Como puede darse cuenta he colocado al final de cada asignación la letra D, esto es para indicarle al compilador que lo trate como un número de longitud 64.
Como estandar de camelCase los atributos de la clase no se escriben en mayuscula sino en minuscula, sin embargo creo que usted intenta crear es una constante por lo cual debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
private static final double IVA = 0.12D;
```

de esta forma el valor nunca podra ser modificado durante la ejecución del programa.

Si desea crear la constante pero asignarla en otra línea de código seria así:

```
private static double IVA;

{
  IVA = 0.12D;
}
```

Sin embargo de esta forma el valor de la constante puede ser modificado durante la ejecucipon del programa, eso si solo desde la clase donde esta declarada.
}

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu ayuda, me enseñaste algo que no sabia.

Comment: El ultimo ejemplo que colocaste @Isaac funciona, pero no es correcto. Ese bloque se va a correr cada vez que se crea una instancia de la clase.... pero la variable la declaraste de instancia así que en realidad está haciendo trabajo adicional cada vez que construyes una instancia.... ese bloque tendría que quedar marcado como static. `static { IVA = 0.12; }`

Comment: @Kuveta, si le fue util, no se le olvide marcarla como respuesta